# (C# Value Doesnt Change) Modifiying Static Variables from Static Callback Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, callback, static-methods, static-variables

Hello i want to ask how to modifiying value static variable from static callback, and read value again. I need to stop while looping when value from static variable change. This is my code.

The problem is value from stepControlEx remain same, it doesnt change when another callback run again and modify the value. It makes my looping stuck and cannot end.

Thanks for helping

```
Private static int stepControl = 0;
Private static int stepControlEx
{
  get { return stepControl;}
  set { stepControl = value;}
}

Private static void CallbackHandle (Object object)
{
  If (object == 0)
  {
    stepControlEx = 0;
    While (stepControlEx == 0)
    {
      //do events
      //stop when stepControl Change
    }
  }
  Else If (object == 1)
  {
    stepControlEx = 1;
    While (stepControlEx == 1)
    {
      //do events
      //stop when stepControl Change
    }
  }
}
```

EDITED (SOLVED):
I tottaly change the algorithm and use thread that process data from queue. Callback function only enqueue input to queue and thread dequeue input to processing, now step control doesn't need as global variable. Thank you

Comment: I don't believe this code should compile for many reasons (Private, While Else doesn't look like C#), could you publish the actual code ?  Additionally Are you sure the while loop actually changes the value ? because you didn't include this code as well. (Also `object` is a reserve keyword which usually is a bad name to chose)

Comment: It is probably Visual Basic. Who changes stepControl value and who calls the CallbackHandle() ?

Comment: @OrelEraki This code only small pieces from my code and compiled in C#. The loop only read the value from stepControl and check it if change.

Comment: @AlexIsayenko CallbackHandle called by pcap.net module, that sniffing network and called when there's a packet receive or send by another application. stepControl change on CallbackHandle when there's a packet that receive or send base on type of packet that determines by keyword.

Comment: This while-loop blocks the execution of the program. Try runing the loop in a separate thread.

Comment: Please post the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks ambiguous. But I have only one comment for your code. If you have a static variable and shared among multiple threads, you need to lock the variable while changing it.
I think you get deadlocks that is why the loop never ends.

Anytime you assign any static variable in a multi-threading environment. you need to to this:

```
lock (new object())
        {
            stepControlEx = 0;
        }
```

Comment: lock is a very simple mechanism to synchronize. There are also other types synchronizations.

Comment: Actually if all you do is accessing the variable, then lock may be totally overkill - the interlocked class has some static methods (add, substract, exchange, read) that go straight to processor directives and are more lightweight than lock. I understand not many people learn multi threaded programming properly. Locking is SLOW and should be a "last resort". More lightweight alternatives exist.